# Gatsby — Error: Cannot find ffprobe after GraphQL request using gatsby-plugin-ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I am getting an error and a crash when trying to retrieve information from a GraphQL request using `gatsby-plugin-ffmpeg`. The issue seems to happen when I add to the query `transcode`. I looked all around and I cannot find an answer for this issue. Does anyone knows a fix for this?

Thank you in advance.

GraphQL error

```
{
  "message": "Failed to fetch",
  "stack": "TypeError: Failed to fetch"
}
```

Request

```
query MyQuery {
  allFile(filter: {relativePath: {eq: "video-test.mp4"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        relativePath
        sourceInstanceName
        name
        childVideoFfmpeg {
          transcode {
            originalName
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Terminal error

```
Error: Cannot find ffprobe

- ffprobe.js:145 
/[fluent-ffmpeg]/lib/ffprobe.js:145:31
```

Packages installed

```
"gatsby-plugin-ffmpeg": "^0.3.1",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.5.0",
"gatsby-transformer-ffmpeg": "^0.3.8",
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Any update on this?

Comment: Hi Leticia. Unfortunately, no luck on my side. Please let me know if you find a solution. I might put a bounty on this.

Comment: No success either :( I decided just import the video directly